# New Installation Boots to Black Screen

Tags: boot, 16.04, fglrx, amd-graphics

I recently installed `Xubuntu 16.04 LTS` on my `HP Pavilion`. Unfortunately, after installing and restarting it immediately boots to a black screen.

Hardware specs are as follows:

- CPU: A4 3300m
- GPU: Radeon HD 6480G (APU)
- RAM: 4GB

Note that I have had the same problem on multiple distributions of Ubuntu starting as far back as 14.04 and on every flavor of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Ubuntu, even Mint).

On those previous installations I added `nomodeset` to my grub commands, and then installed `fglrx` which actually fixed the problem (despite suggestions to fix the problem saying that `fglrx` should be uninstalled). Now, however, `fglrx` is no longer supported on Ubuntu 16.04 so this method doesn't work.

My understanding is that it is a bug with the open source driver, but this seems unlikely since I've not seen any bug reports on it, and this issue has been around for at least 2 years.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: I had similar issues for Lubuntu a while back and had to fiddle with GRUB settings.  This https://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround got me started - you might have to try different GRUB options.

Comment: From what I can tell, that post would amount to the same as using the "nomodeset" option (for AMD cards I would use radeon.modeset=0), but this would result in the computer booting in software rendering mode which is undesirable. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to fix it!

Instead of "nomodeset" in the grub options, I put "acpi_osi=Linux", and it booted normally with open-source Radeon drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove "quiet" and "splash", and add "nomodeset".  I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on a Dell 7010  with a Dell 20" P2012H LCD Monitor and had a similar problem. On booting (after the grub screen) the monitor would go black. I found that I could turn the monitor off and back on and it would function properly.  I set the monitor to use the display port input instead of the auto-detect option and the problem went away.