# Black Screen on upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 16.04, amd-graphics, hp-pavilion

My computer boots to a black screen after I upgraded from Ubuntu 15.04 to 16.04 LTS. Every time, I need to open and close the lid to get to the screen.

My machine is a HP Pavilion g6 with AMD Quad-Core A6-3420M with Radeon 6520G graphics card.

I tried different options, but none seem to work.

1. Used different GRUB parameters to boot. I currently have `splash
   radeon.dpm=1`. In addition, I tried `quiet splash radeon.dpm=1`,
   just `radeon.dpm=1` and `no splash radeon.dpm=1`. Then I tried
   `acpi_osi=Linux` with some of these combinations, but to no avail. I picked up suggestions for parameters from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785145/new-installation-boots-to-black-screen).
2. If I use `nomodeset` or `radeon.modeset=0`, then the computer boots
   correctly - or seems to. However, the radeon driver does not load
   up: running `glxinfo` gives, among other things

   `OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
    OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)`

Also:

```
thomas@localhost:~$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic   root=UUID=c6ef3987-05d3-4213-92ed-49442645ebaa ro quiet splash nomodeset radeon.dpm=1 acpi_sleep=nonvs vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-38-generic root=UUID=c6ef3987-05d3-4213-92ed-49442645ebaa ro quiet splash nomodeset radeon.dpm=1 acpi_sleep=nonvs vt.handoff=7
[    3.217595] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    3.269065] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    3.269092] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[    3.309976] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[    3.310007] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
[   16.994342] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[   16.994387] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

Further, heating is intense, Suspend does not work on closing the lid, can't project from the laptop...the list goes on.

Without nomodeset, after the lid opening and closing sequence`glxinfo` gives

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD SUMO (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
```

And other things also look fine.

3. When booting without `nomodeset` on battery, a certain combination of `enter` and `spacebar` immediately after selecting Ubuntu from the Grub menu and before the black screen appears, results in a normal boot after a black screen for a brief period. I have not yet figured out the right combination of key presses or timing that could consistently boot me up, so my problem remains.

Graphics card details:

```
thomas@localhost:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G] [1002:9647]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: About 1: Where did you get those parameters from? About 2: Not loading the driver is precisely the point of those parameters. Everything described after is related. I suggest backing up and then install 16.04 from scratch. 15.04>16.04 is a weird upgrade path.

Comment: The HP Pavilion G6 used to work quite well with *fglrx* but no proprietary drivers are available for 16.04 and part of the upgrade process should have been removing *fglrx* and replacing it with either *radeon* or *amdgpu*, both open-source, and it may have disrupted something.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: I upgraded 15.04->15.10->16.04, which is what Ubuntu recommends. I had the same problem in 15.04, but _fglrx_ did not solve it. In fact, the screen would not come up at all. So I had to go back to the open source driver and remove _fglrx_. From that perspective, the _radeon_ driver is a huge improvement. While upgrading to 16.04, I ran the steps to remove _fglrx_ to ensure that it is removed. Thanks anyway for trying to help!

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Parameters were taken from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/785145/new-installation-boots-to-black-screen) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Please edit and update the question with that information because it is very relevant and shouldn't be lost in comments. The suggestion stands: Fresh16.04. Test in a live session. If the problem persists I would suspect hardware. I remember yours and many other AMD APU based working quite well last year with fglrx and one remarkable A10.

Comment: @Thanks, I added the links into point 1. _fglrx_ **never** worked for me - though I tried it out multiple times last year. Finally reverted to nomodeset and open source driver, with the same [heating, projecting and lid-closing problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/666296/heating-projecting-and-lid-closing-problems-in-ubuntu-gnome-15-04) .  Will try out the fresh install - but can't do so now without jeopardising the project I'm working on.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: I finally was able to do a fresh install. Since 16.10 is available, I used 16.10. However, no change in status quo: I still need to close and open lid. Or press the on button to send it into hibernate and then press it again.

Comment: Still no progress.... any suggestions anyone?